# How do I create a bootable copy of an internal hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, bootable-media

I have an old laptop that is starting to die. I have really important programs and files on that laptop, and I'm worried that the hard drive will soon fail. 
Is there a way to create an exact copy of the internal hard drive of my laptop and allow me to boot it on another device? 
I want to make sure that I have a bootable backup with all the programs and files still operational, just in case the hard drive fails. 
Thanks!

Comment: You should back up your data, not your entire drive. Putting the hard drive, or a copy of it, from your current laptop into another laptop will not work. Drivers are hardware-specific and there will be too many errors due to the differences in the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply your HDD image to an identical machine, and even then there may be conflicts. However, you *can* restore the image to your old machine if you replace the HDD  with the same size and model, or *possibly* a larger HDD.

The easiest way to make an image in Windows is to use a third-party tool, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). That image requires another HDD, external or internal, with room enough for all your used space (usually much less than the size of your PC's HDD).

That image will *not* be bootable, so also create a bootable USB device using the imaging software, which you will then use to move the image onto the replacement HDD. The boot USB flash drive need be only a few GB to hold the OS, e.g., WinPE, and the backup software.

It's a good idea to have a disk image even if there is no issue with your HDD, in case of sudden disk failure or malware infection.

Comment: ddrescue can also clone dying drives under Linux.